# show actual error in result message mongoose node validation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose, axios

I am working with mongoose and axios in node.js/react and need to obtain the specific validation error in the client side so that i can update the form. In this case the user email is already  the database and not unique. the error returned to the front end appears useless. i tried err.message on the front end but it gives me nothing. How do i call the specific error message telling me the actual error?

FRONTEND API IS CALLED AND INCLUDES:

```
  API.createUser({
    userEmail: this.state.profile.email.toLowerCase(),
   })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

BACKEND CONTROLLER

```
  db.WmUser
      .create(req.body)
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
```

MONGOOSE SCHEMA INCLUDES:

```
userEmail: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
```

RESULT RETURNS FRONT END ERROR:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

RESULT RETURNS IN THE BACKEND IN CONTROLLER:

if i use the following code in the controller i get the error message i need but don't know how to bring it back to the front end:

```
  .catch(err=> console.log(err.message))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the way i was calling the error in the front end. it needs to be error.response incase anyone runs into this problem

FUNCTION CALLING AXIOS IN FRONT END

```
  API.createUser({
    userEmail: this.state.profile.email.toLowerCase(),
        })
   .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
    if(error.response.data.code == 11000){
      console.log("THE EMAIL IS ALREADY IN THE DATABASE");
    }
    console.log(error.response);
   })
```

AXIOS FUNCTION IN API file

```
createUser: function(userData){ 
     return axios.post("/api/wmUser/", userData);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below in backend controller

```
var WmUser = require('./path/to/WmUser.js')//your db mdel path
WmUser(req.body).save().then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Creation fail error---->', err);
        res.status(422).json(err)
    });
```

Comment: nope says it's deprecated to use res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body).. wierd thing is i can see the error in the backend if i use       .catch(err=> console.log(err.message)) just have no idea how to bring back the error message to the frontend